# Finding all select inputs with in a loop using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a loop that creates a datastring for an ajax call. Here is the code:

```
    $(':input','#texes-test-entry-0').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').each(function(){
        varStr = $(this).attr("id").split('-');
        dataString = dataString + '&' + varStr[1] + '=' + $(this).val();
    });
```

For all of the text inputs $(this).val()     gets me the value that I need, but for the select inputs, I don't need the text value but the selected option value.

How do I catch the the select inputs and treat them differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to treat select elements differently, the `val` method will get the selected value from the select.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var data = [];
  $(':input','#texes-test-entry-0').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').each(function(){
    varStr = $(this).attr("id").split('-');
    data.push(varStr[1] + '=' + $(this).val().replace(/%/g,'%37').replace(/&/g,'%38'));
  });
  var dataString = data.join('&');
  alert(dataString);
});
</script>

<form id="texes-test-entry-0">
  <input type="text" id="x-id1" value="as%&df" />
  <select id="x-id2">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Output:

```
id1=as%37%38df&id2=2
```

Comment: I figured this out. I had something else wrong. :-) On another note could you explain the reason for two things: 1. Why are you using the push and join methods instead of just creating the string. 2. Why did you use the two replace methods. I am trying to learn here, so if the answers are obvious, please humor me.

Comment: @resonantmedia: Creating separate strings and then join them together is more efficient than using += to build a string. Each time you use += you create a new string which grows each time, so by the time you are done you have moved around a lot more data than ends up in the final string. The replace calls are for URL encoding the % and & characters, which will break the result if they are left unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an if inside the loop that selects all inputs and check if the current element has option, if yes don't process it.

```
if($(this).has('option'))
{
<ignore>
}
else
{
<process>
}
```

Comment: That still returns both select and text inputs. Any other ideas?